# How to automatically add decimal point on user input on form

Tags: angular

On an input number field when the user starts typing I want to have the field automatically convert it to currency with cents first.

For example, if I input 1, it will show .01 in the input box.

If I input 1234 it will show 12.34 in the field. While I am typing it will start showing .01, then .12, then 1.23, then finally 12.34 when I am finished.

I believe Paypal does something similar to this on their site when a user is transferring balances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this functionality by using the ngx-currency package. Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-currency to find more information.

I currently use this on a project and it has saved me many headaches from trying to self-program currency logic.

Comment: Thanks, after doing more research this is about what I came up with as well. Discovered very quickly that I was going to need a package to use or spend several days writing up and testing a new solution for it. 

I was hoping there was simple way that was already built in or a method - but guess not! :) Thanks for assurance.